# Can't take screenshot when right clicking file

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, screenshot

When I right click a file with my file manager, I am unable to take a screenshot.

Other print screen attempts do work.

Is there a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is absolutely normal.

In such case I use delayed screenshot as follows:

```
mate-screenshot -d 3
```

above `-d` is for

> -d, --delay=seconds            Take screenshot after specified delay [in seconds]

and `3` is 3 seconds delay. You can use this delay for doing right click.

Comment: *It is absolutely normal.* Could you elaborate on that? Using delayed screenshot is a workaround that I would like to avoid because it requires more interactions and time.